# Knitr: figure legend too big

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr, figure

When I knit a Tufte handout pdf the legends of some figures are often too large. I'm knitting a `fig.fullwidth=TRUE` section and have varied the `fig.width=` argument from 2 to 50 to see if they make any difference. When I specify `fig.width=2` I end up with a small figure and the legend expands hugely to fill the space:

[image: Knitted figure with fig.width = 2]

Obviously the next step was to try a larger `fig.width` but these stopped making any difference after about `fig.width=10` (which is still better though):

[image: Knitted figure with fig.width = 10]

I assume the fig.width is the width in inches, so this makes sense as the paper size I'm using is A4 so about 8 inches.

My question is, how do I reduce the size of the legend further so it takes up a more appropriate size? I've tried manually setting the font sizes with:

```
theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 9),
      legend.text = element_text(size = 8))
```

but these have had no affect to the knitr legend (although they do affect the plot when manually plotted as expected).

Minimal reproducible example (paste into a .Rmd file and knit):

````
---
title: "knitr: figure legend too big"
documentclass: article
classoption: a4paper
output: rmarkdown::tufte_handout
---

  ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
require("knitr")
require("rgdal")
require("rgeos")
require("maptools")
require("ggplot2")
```

```{r, fig.cap="test", fig.fullwidth=TRUE, fig.width=10}
# About 650k
download.file("https://census.edina.ac.uk/ukborders/easy_download/prebuilt/shape/England_gor_2011_gen.zip",
              destfile = "regions.zip")
unzip("regions.zip")
regions <- readOGR(dsn = ".", "england_gor_2011_gen")
regions@data$test <- as.character(1:nrow(regions@data))

regions_f <- fortify(regions, region = "name")
regions_f <- merge(regions_f, regions@data, by.x = "id", by.y = "name")

ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = regions_f, aes(long, lat, group = group, fill = test),
               colour = "black") +
  coord_equal() +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 9),  # doesn't seem to make
      legend.text = element_text(size = 8))     # a difference to knitr
```
````

As always, thanks for looking at this.

Comment: I tried to run your code. After installing a bunch of packages it still fails with `Error: isTRUE(gpclibPermitStatus()) ist nicht TRUE`. If you can give some advice on how to reproduce the problem, others/I might be able to find an answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks for checking @CL. I've tried my script on fresh R sessions on two different machines (one Windows, one Linux) and don't encounter any errors. I didn't think I used any `gpclib` calls so I'm not sure why it's checking. Could you try re-installing `rgeos` and see if it makes any difference?

Comment: Huh? Reinstalling `rgeos` helped - although I *installed* that package only minutes ago. Anyways, time to turn to the actual question …

Comment: Thanks @CL. `rgeos`, `maptools`, and `rgdal` are great tools, but sometimes they're just *weird*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that is due to the fact that maps have to set the aspect ratio to `1`. The default figure height in `tufte::tufte_handout()` is 2.5, so even if the figure width is as large as 10, the actual map size is still like 2.5 x 2.5. When you increase `fig.width`, you also need to increase `fig.height`, e.g.

````
```{r, fig.cap="test", fig.fullwidth=TRUE, fig.width=6, fig.height=6}
````

Actually, when you only set `fig.width=10`, **knitr** did generate a 10 x 2.5 PDF image, but **rmarkdown** has enabled the figure cropping feature by default, so the large white margins on the left and right of the figure are cropped, and you ended up with a 2.5 x 2.5 figure.